# How to get a child of a mongo collections by the key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, key, mongoose, mongodb-query

I ve got a collection users that look like this :

```
{
_id: myid,
name : 'blabla',
ia : {
       [0]-> 'an id',
       [1]-> 'a second id'
      }
}
```

And i want to have only my first id of ia, so i tried something like that :

```
User.find({ _id: id, ia :{ key : indexia} }, ['ia']).populate('ia').run(rendu);
```

where id= myid, and indexia=0.

If i don t put that part : " ia :{ key : indexia}" i get all my ia... but i want only one.

Hope i was clear. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request correctly. What exactly do you get, and what do you want to get? Do you have actual / expected JSON to post?

Comment: My collection :

{ "_id": { "$oid" : "4fac50bda7087c0c14000001" }, 
"ia": [ "4fbec72f7f0257a815000004", "4fbed51b53795ffc06000001", "4fbee32403949f7c03000001" ], 
"mail": "a@a.fr", 
"name": "a", 
"password": "5267768822ee624d48fce15ec5ca79cbd602cb7f4c2157a516556991f22ef8c7b5ef7b18d1ff41c59370efb0858651d44a936c11b7b144c48fe04df3c6a3e8da" }

the info ive got : the user _id (4fac50bda7087c0c14000001) and the key reference of an ia :(the first, the second or the third). 

And i would like too retrieve an id of an ia, for exemple :4fbed51b53795ffc06000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help
It worker like that:

```
User.find({ _id: id }).only('ia').slice('ia', indexia, 1).populate('ia').run(rendu);
```

The only('ia') don t work, but not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB `find()` command is intended to match an entire document.

When you run the following query

```
{ _id: id, ia :{ key : indexia} }
```

... this means *"where `_id` equals `id` and `ia` equals the object `{key:0}`"*. That's probably **not** what you want.

> If i don t put that part : " ia :{ key : indexia}" i get all my ia... but i want only one.

It sounds like you want to return a piece of a given document. The documentation for that is [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields). In your case it would look like this:

```
find({ _id: id}, { 'ia.0' : 1 })
```

The first part of the find will find the document. The second part will return specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection appears to have the schema:

```
{ "_id" : "id",
  "ia"  : ["id1","id2","id3"],
   etc.
}
```

In this case, the query to get just the first "id" of the "ia" field would be:

```
find({}, { "ia" : {$slice:1  } })
```

You can read more about $slice operator [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements).
Mongoose documents its support for the $slice operator on the [query page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/query.html).
Hope this helps!